# Turn of Compatibility Mode Off Programatically

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, ie8-compatibility-mode

The top of my web page is as follows

```
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

I am using IE8 and IE9. Compatibility view is checked in both. I was under the impression that the above would overwrite that?

The reason I need to overwrite it is we have X users and can't expect all X to switch if off themselves

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, "IE=edge" doesn't turn off compatibility view, but it does make the browser render in the newest mode despite that. So the user agent string sent to the server in the HTTP request will be IE 7, but when it renders the page (and to JavaScript) it will look like a newer version.